# Applying MEMBER_CAPTION to the return value of ClosingPeriod

Tags: ssas, mdx

The following does not error, or bug, just returns a blank result set.

I realize there are other functions I can use but for the sake of experimentation I'd like to stick with `ClosingPeriod`

Why is it returning a blank?
How do I amend it so it returns yesterday?

```
WITH MEMBER [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[member_caption] AS
    ClosingPeriod(
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day]
        ).MEMBER_CAPTION
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY 
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[member_caption]
    ON COLUMNS
FROM [OurCube]
```

---

**EDIT**

The MSDN documentation for the ClosingPeriod function **[is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145584.aspx)** and states:

> • If a level expression is specified, the ClosingPeriod function uses
>   the dimension that contains the specified level and returns the last
>   sibling among the descendants of the default member at the specified
>   level.
>
> • If both a level expression and a member expression are specified,
>   the ClosingPeriod function returns the last sibling among the
>   descendants of specified member at the specified level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is because the default member of the [Date].[Date - Calendar Month] is not in the [Calendar Day] level; so this equivalent to :

```
ClosingPeriod( [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day], null )
```

obsviously null has no descendants and ClosingPeriod does not return anything. Perhaps you want something like:

```
ClosingPeriod( 
  [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day],
  [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].defaultMember 
)
```

Comment: +1 thanks Marc - always glad to see you contributing to my MDX questions! The `defaultMember` of the hierarchy is `[All Dates]` so makes sense that it does not exist in [Calendar Day] level. I'll add a little more info to OP as my head is slightly twisted by the `MSDN` documentation!

Comment: ...although the first point in MSDN says `the ClosingPeriod function uses the dimension that contains the specified level and returns the last sibling among the descendants of the default member at the specified level.` which sounds like my attempt should have worked ?

Comment: Yes the doc is not very clear but it says 'default member at the specified level' and if you check the example given by MS you'll see that a hierarchy containing a single level is used meaning the default member fo the hierarchy is in the specified level.

Comment: Ok - if you expand the example `ClosingPeriod(level,member) - level is ancestor` [IN HERE](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/ClosingPeriod.html) it says "Returns NULL if the level is of lower depth than the member." which is effectively what is happening as [All Dates] is higher than the level [Calendar Day] ?